# Unable to resize image using image_tag (rails activestorage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

i'm using activestorage rails 5 in my project for uploading images when image uploads it did not resize to my given size in image tag. it only working with square images.
help me i want to store images in given size

image_tag code -

```
image_tag(current_user.avatar.variant(:resize => "250x250"
                      ), :crop => :fill)
```

Comment: Do you have minimagick installed?

Comment: yes i've installed minimagick gem

Comment: Bro you are using image_tag, try sizing using its attibute.  image_tag(current_user.avatar.image, size: '250x250')

Comment: no bro @vishal it did not work it gives an error

Comment: I've made changes in CSS file & now it's working

Answer (score 3):

Since you wish to save the image after resizing it so you should do

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.new("input.jpg") do |b|
  b.resize "250x250>"
end
```

before you save the image.

The other method is that to show the image in a specific size regardless of what size you have saved it in.

```
image_tag(current_user.avatar.image, size: '250x250')
```

I hope this helps you out

Comment: I want to store the image which is uploaded by user in your code i have to hard code the image name. thanx any way :-)